# R sweep a dataframe for characters, but only in the parameter columns

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, character

If I have a .csv that looks a bit like this (names and places have been changed to protect the innocent) and is read in as a dataframe df

```
     Species          Place  param1 param2 param3
1     D.lice        on head 123.123     39  65.43
2 X.elephant        up butt 234.400  *****       
3   B.booger        in nose  32.000   <NA>  $%(*0
4    F.farts      blame dog  -9.990     43
```

How would I remove all character "cells" and replace them with an empty value "" (not NULL), leaving only numbers (and, importantly, columns that have num (or numerical) type, so that I can stop errors like this `Error in hist.default(testParam) : 'x' must be numeric` where `testParam` is one of the columns?

I thought of `sweep`, and have been trying various implementations of `replace`, but I can't seem to get either of them to work where they only affect the parameter columns, and where they can pick up *any* possible character/strings that have been inserted by the various parameter generators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to detect values in `param` columns which have only numbers (with maybe one dot) and replace values that don't and then afterwards convert it to numeric.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  species = letters[1:5],
  param1 = c("123.56", "23", "ds%", "12.ab", "123"),
  param2 = c("%23", "43.23", "abc", "45", "0.23"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    across(
      matches("^param[0-9]+"),
      ~ifelse(str_detect(.x, "^[0-9]+\\.{0,1}[0-9]*$"), .x, NA_character_) %>%
        as.numeric()
    )
  )
```

gives:

```
  species param1 param2
1       a 123.56     NA
2       b  23.00  43.23
3       c     NA     NA
4       d     NA  45.00
5       e 123.00   0.23
```

where `param` columns are numeric.

Note: `param` columns must be character and not factors. If they are factors you need to convert them to characters.

Comment: I am using this inside a loop that tests parameter columns one at a time, so with your guidance on the `ifelse` and `str_detect` I eded up using this:
`if(is.character(df[ ,i])){testing <- as.numeric(ifelse(str_detect(df[ ,i], "\\d"), df[ ,i], NA))}'`